# Javascript - Strange behaviours with getting elements of div in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get elements of a div in an array in javascript. But i am getting strange behaviour. First i use a `for` loop to print some dashes in a div with ID `dashes`

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
         $("#dashes").append("_ ");
    }

and in <body> i have,
<div id="dashes">
 </div>
```

Then i need to get the content of `dashes` at some later time and replace some `dash` with some alphabet for which i used following code for first getting `dashes` in array (so i can replace particular dash with alphabet):

```
 var divData = $("#dashes").html().split('');
```

But i am getting strange behavior with this. This is the array which i get:
`,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,`

I also tried with `.split(' ');` but again i'm not getting the correct results.

Where am i doing wrong ? Can you suggest some other approach for replacing particular dash in `dashes` div ?

Comment: What do you expect `divData` to be? You're splitting on nothing

Comment: How about a jsFiddle?

Comment: If you're wanting to split on a space, then try `.split(' ');` instead.

Comment: Empty "cells" are probably newlines and tabs in the HTML, try to split `.text().trim()` instead of `.html()`.

Comment: @tymeJV @War10ck i tried with `.split(' ');` as well but couldn't get desired

Comment: are you sure the div does not have any sub element or enter etc? try <div></div> you should only see "_"s in the result array.

Comment: I have updated the question with `div` -

Comment: So, you want to get every dash in `$("dashes")` into an array and then replace each dash with a letter?

Comment: Yes but replace only a particular dash with a letter, which user would have entered. (I'm making a Hangmang game infact)

Comment: I was just thinking, I wonder if the OP is trying to create a HangMan game, and then I saw your last comment! :) - Perhaps if you'd have explained that in your original question you might not have got the down vote (which wasnt me BTW :) ) Your original question isn't very clear about what you are trying to do and what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure what you were actually asking in your question / what was wrong, but as shown in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3B3MJ/

your loop to append "_ " (dash space) to the div works fine:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    $("#dashes").append("_ ");
};
```

and the split functions work fine (I've shown examples of split using an empty string as the delimiter, and also split using a space)

```
$("#dashes").html().split('');
$("#dashes").html().split(' ');
```

In my fiddle, everything works as one would expect, so really not sure what problem you are experiencing ??

Cheers

Nathan